# C# select multiple elements with length condition

Tags: c#, linq, list, select, conditional-statements

I have a list containing strings, and I would like some hints/help how to select multiple elements so that the total length of the selected elements are e.g. 13 in length.

I have an idea that using linq might be a good solution, but I'm not really that into linq yet.

Thanks in advance :)

Here are some code that I've tried before my post. But since the file contains +2500 lines it takes too long time.

```
List<string> textList = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\text"));
List<string> newTextList = new List<string>();
foreach (string x in textList)
{
    foreach (string y in textList)
    {
        if ((x + y).Length == 13)
        {
                newTextList.Add(x + " " + y);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a rewrite of the code:

```
List<string> textList = new List<string>(File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\text"));
List<string> newTextList = new List<string>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
    List<string> list1 = new List<string>(textList.Where(x => x.Length == i));    
    List<string> list2 = new List<string>(textList.Where(x => x.Length == 13-i));
    foreach (string x in list1)
    {
        foreach (string y in list2)
        {
            newTextList.Add(x + " " + y);
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any way to do something like this below?

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>(textList.Where(x,y => x.Length + y.Lenght == 13));
```

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Try something and post it. That's the minimum to receive a "hint/help"

Comment: Can you please give a good example of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for code.

Comment: You need the first set of such elements or all the combinations?

Comment: @VMAtm basically all combinations.

Comment: @user2071220 You know, this is not as basic as you think. This is a huge task. I think you should start with sorting the string array on element's length, and after that do some work on the part of short ones. From other side, you can write a `Union` query, but this will be a very time consuming task.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
int currentLength=0;
var items = list.TakeWhile(x => (currentLength += x.Length ) <= 13);
```

Comment: captured `currentLength` variable warning, code might not work correct depend on Framework version

Comment: @Melnikovl thanks for your comment. I didn't know that. Could you please point me a link where I could read more about this. Thank you very much in advance. Once I get your link, I will delete my post.

Comment: Sorry, code is fine, closure not affected this code